# Plugin options with googlemap iframe

Tags: plugin-development, google-maps

I have put google map in text option of plugin.The text input value is

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps?q=The+Metropolitan+Museum+of+Art&amp;sll=40.779532,-73.963346&amp;cid=4264808743088595450&amp;hq=The+Metropolitan+Museum+of+Art&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=40.780061,-73.963473&amp;spn=0.003242,0.008433&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://www.google.com/maps?q=The+Metropolitan+Museum+of+Art&amp;sll=40.779532,-73.963346&amp;cid=4264808743088595450&amp;hq=The+Metropolitan+Museum+of+Art&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=40.780061,-73.963473&amp;spn=0.003242,0.008433&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

while displaying the field value server response with page not found error.To display I have used

```
$options = get_option('googlemap_options');
echo html_entity_decode($options['map_url']);
```

what is the correct way to display google map?

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue with or the steps, are you trying to save a google map iframe embed in an option then display it at a later date? Have you tried not using `html_entity_decode`? Where is the code that saves the option? Have you verified the original embed code from google maps works on its own?

Comment: Yes it works.If I don't use html_entity_decode it display the original code with iframe.

Comment: Which is what you want, so there's your answer, Im guessing that you didnt encode before saving

Comment: Yes Now I have got it.If It works I will accept yours.Thanks